# Attemping dynamic displaying a usercontrol,how to implement this？

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want utilize a custom control（ui like a button） dynamic show a tree under it when user click it.And hide tree when custom control lost focus.
how to get it ?
(In addition can't use Form control.)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

Create a control(tree) which is hidden from the beginning.

```
yourControl.Visible = false;
```

Create your button and your click eventhandler

```
yourButton.Click += yourButton_Click;
private void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourControl.Visible = true;
}
```

To hide when focus is lost, you need to create another method/eventhandler:

```
yourButton.LostFocus += yourButton_LostFocus;
    void yourButton_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourControl.Visible = false;
    }
```